# Windows cmd.exe does not get open with python subprocess

Tags: subprocess

I am executing below code but I can not see any command prompt opened.
is this a correct code what I have written.

```
import subprocess
sp = subprocess.Popen(['runas', '/user:Administrator', 'cmd.exe'],stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
sp.communicate('abc')
```

or

```
import subprocess
sp = subprocess.Popen(['runas', '/user:Administrator', 'notepad.exe'],stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
sp.communicate('abc')
```

Can you please help me resolving this query ?